# Getting parserror while sending JSON data to Webmethod

Tags: json

I am getting parseerror for my below ajax call, what can be wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
var contact1 = {
     "id":"5",
     "name": "fsdfsd"
};

  var jsonString = "{\"JsData\":" + JSON.stringify(contact1) + "}";

$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "Default.aspx/ReceiveData",   
             data: jsonString,
            // data: DTO,      
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(msg) {
alert(msg);
                },
                error: function(response,ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    alert("error:" + ajaxOptions);

                }
            });
```

My server side webmethod is

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ReceiveData(contact1 JsData)
    {
        //JsonTextParser parser = new JsonTextParser();
        //JsonObject obj = parser.Parse(JsData);
        //foreach (JsonObject field in obj as JsonObjectCollection)
        //{
        //    string v = field.ToString();
        //}
        return "success";
    }

public class contact1
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. I am using 2.0 framework, I forgot to add Ajax related references in my web.config. I added those manually, & it worked.

Comment: FANTASTICALLY, OUTSTANDING AND ROCKING..SANJIVANI YOU ROCK. I WAS LOOKING FOR THIS SOLUTION FOR THE ENTIRE DAY AND YOUR POST HELPED ME.
THANKS A TON.